React hook form - unregister TypeError: Cannot delete property 'input1' of [object Object] (or of #<Object>)
In my form I have a component which should save values as an object.
It contains a checkbox and 2 inputs.
When I check the checkbox I want inputs to appear, when I uncheck - they should be hidden and values unregistered.
Here is when the error appears:
TypeError: Cannot delete property 'resource' of [object Object]
at unset (unset.ts:27:1)
at unregister (useForm.ts:892:1)

"react-hook-form": "~7.4.0"
I'm expecting getValues to return
 {
  myData: {
    enabled: true,
    input1: 'testValue',
    input2: 'testValue2',
  }
} 

or
 {
  myData: {
    enabled: false,
  }
} 

This is how my component looks like (a bit simplified for the purpose of this question)
export const useConfigurationFormContext = <
    T extends FieldValues
>(): UseConfigurationFormReturn<T> => {
    const { register, ...rest } = useFormContext<T>();
    return {
        register: (name, options) => {
            const { ref, ...rest } = register(name, options);
            return {
                onInputRef: (element: HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement) =>
                    (ref as React.RefCallback<
                        HTMLInputElement | HTMLTextAreaElement
                    >)(element),
                ...rest,
            };
        },
        ...rest,
    };
};

  const { watch, unregister, register } = useConfigurationFormContext<FieldValues>();

    const dataEnabledPath = `${FormAttributes.MY_DATA}.${MyDataAttributes.ENABLED}`;
    const input1Path = `${FormAttributes.MY_DATA}.${MyDataAttributes.INPUT_1}`;
    const input2Path = `${FormAttributes.MY_DATA}.${MyDataAttributes.INPUT_2}`;   

    const isDataEnabled = watch(dataEnabledPath);

    useEffect(() => {
        if (!isDataEnabled ) {
            unregister([
                input1Path,
                input2Path,
            ]);
        }       
    }, [isDataEnabled, unregister]);

 return (
        <div>         
             <Controller
                 render={({ field: { onChange, value } }) => (
                     <Checkbox
                         onChange={onChange}
                         checked={value === undefined ? false : value}
                     >
                         My checkbox
                     </Checkbox>
                 )}
                 name={dataEnabledPath}
             />              
            {isDataEnabled && (
                <Input
                    {...register(input1Path)}               
                />
            )}
            {isDataEnabled && (
                <Input
                    {...register(input2Path)}               
                />
            )}           
        </div>
    );

It works fine if I unregister the whole object, but doesn't if I want to unregister only some of it's attributes.
Using setValue(undefined) is not a solution for me because they fields are still there and the form is not passing the validation (inputs are obligatory if they exist).
I can't use shouldUnregister: true for the whole form.
When I used shouldUnregister: true inside all the inputs' register, the error changed into TypeError: Cannot delete property 'input1' of #<Object>
